# how to handle unknown categorical value in one hot encoding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe on which I do one hot encoding using `get_dummies` method.

Here is the sample code -

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.DataFrame( ['a','a,b','a,c'], columns = ['category'])
X.head()
  category
0        a
1      a,b
2      a,c
```

Here is how I do one hot encoding

```
X_transformed = pd.concat([X, X['category'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')], axis=1)
X_transformed.head()
  category  a  b  c
0        a  1  0  0
1      a,b  1  1  0
2      a,c  1  0  1
```

The problem is, that when I get a record with an unknown categorical value, I dont know how to best handle it -

```
y = pd.DataFrame(['a','d'], columns = ['category'])
y.head()
  category
0        a
1        d
```

If i again do `get_dummies` on this new dataframe, then I get something like

```
y_transformed = pd.concat([y, y['category'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')], axis=1)
y_transformed.head()

  category  a  d
0        a  1  0
1        d  0  1
```

whereas my expected output is

```
  category  a  b  c
0        a  1  0  0
1        d  0  0  0
```

because category **d** was never seen before in the first place, so I want to neglect it by making all flags of columns `a,b,c` as 0.

How can I achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on `axis=1` with `fill_value=0`:

```
y_transformed = y_transformed.reindex(X_transformed.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
  category  a  b  c
0        a  1  0  0
1        d  0  0  0
```

Comment: thank you Shubham for this answer. it works. I have 2 questions - First - The original column name has to be a part of the `X_transformed.columns` list? Second - What does reindex do?

Comment: Yes, the original columns need to be part of `X_transformed`. `reindex` conforms the index of dataFrame to new index with optional filling logic in this case we have used `fill_value=0`